# Polluting the global scope with Browserify

Tags: javascript, browserify

I've recently started using [Browserify](http://browserify.org/) and I was wondering if that I'm doing is polluting the global scope.

I have a `main.js`:

```
var Person = require('./Animate/Animate.js');

var me = new Person('John');

me.sayHello();
```

Which is the start point of my project and it has a dependency on another file(`Animate/Animate.js`):

```
var $ = require('jquery');
function Person(name)
{
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function() {
    $('body').html(':3');
    alert('Hello! My name is ' + this.name + ', nice to meet you, sir. New version please.');
}

module.exports = Person;
```

in `Animate.js` I first declare my "class" and then add a method to it.At the very end of the script I export it to a module.

By not wrapping my code in `Animate.js` with a function like:

```
module.exports = function() { // My Person "class" will be here }
```

Or like:

```
(function() { // Paste Animate.js content as it is now here... })()
```

Does it mean I've polluted the global scope or because I'm using browserify it will automatically when creating the `bundle.js` file will ensure that I don't pollute the global scope?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it won't pollute your global scope.

I am working for months with browserify and I see this as best method to describe classes.

Check the browserify build and see how beautifully it is wrapped so as not to pollute the global scope.